# Proof of the existence of a holomorphic function from a simply connected domain to itselfs

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $U$ is simply connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$, and let $P$ be a point in $U$. Prove that for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a  unique holomorphic function $f:U \to U$ such that $f(P)=P$ and $f'(P)=e^{it}$.

Some of my ideas: this is a problem from 2011 UCLA PhD qualifications. Seeing the unique, I want to use the automorphism of the unit disk or Riemann mapping theorem, but I can not construct it. Thanks for your answer very much.

Comment: Riemann mapping theorem is a good idea. Can you solve it for the case that $U$ is the unit disk and $P = 0$? Can you then “transform” to solution to an arbitrary simply connected domain?

Comment: Please, learn how to use LateX (examine my edition of your text).

Comment: What do you mean exactly by $f'(P)=e^{it}$ ? It isn't clear for me.

Comment: To be more explicit, $f'(P)$ is a set of numbers, while $e^{it}$ is a number. They cannot be equal. Even if you mean $\{e^{it}\}$, that would make $f$ an affine function, and other than disks, there are no simply connected domains with curves $b(t)$ such that $P$ is preserved under every map of the form $e^{it}z + b(t)$.

Comment: P is a point of C,I'm sorry...

Comment: @Martin R，but Riemann mapping theorem can not control the derivative

Comment: And yet, if $g$ is a Riemann map and $h$ is a rotation of the unit disk, it still might be possible to control the derivative of $g^{-1}\circ h\circ g$ even if you can't control the derivative of $g$ itself.

Comment: @Greg Martin，however，g is not linear,thus you still can not control the derivative

Comment: I really encourage you to do the actual computation I suggested, rather than find reasons to think it won't work without trying it.

Comment: I know that,thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Riemman Mapping Theorm,there exists a unique conformal map $\phi$:$\mathbb{U}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{D}$
where $\phi$(P)=0,thus for all t$\in$ $\mathbb{R}$,denote h=$e^it$,consider the map:
{g=$\phi$$\circ$h$\circ$$\phi^-1$}\
then:g(P)=P and g'(P)=$\phi$'(0) *$e^it$ * 1/$\phi$'(0)=$e^it$ which satisfies.
Thanks for all of your hints!